# How do you check currently downloaded version and download latest version of SymPy?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am currently using a windows computer and installed SymPy with pip install SymPy.

Comment: `pip list` shows the names and versions of all currently installed modules. `pip list --outdated` shows what needs to be upgraded, including the installed version and the current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pip list` to show the names and versions of all currently installed packages. `pip list --outdated` will also show outdated packages including their version and the latest version available. To upgrade to the latest version of a package, use `pip install --upgrade <package name>`. To get more information on pip and the available commands view the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/).